# Form not posting data to controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla2.5

I am facing a strange problem that is, Whenever I have submit my form it pop-up an error like "***all fields are required***". When I debug it, I found that whenever form  submitted, don't get any post data in my controller, it is an empty array.

All things are working fine on my localhost. I have searched for it and come to this conclusion that this is a problem with my `.htacess` file. I have set the rule for adding **trailing slash** in to that and found that this create a problem.

So i want to know, how can i remove this rule for particular task perform in my component. Any suggestions would be helpful. here 's the code of adding trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Start –301 redirect for "http://" to "http://www"
rewritecond %{http_host} ^testdomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.testsdomain.com/$1 [r=301,L]
# End - 301 redirect rule

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem with changing the rule with below and start working and adding **trailing slash** to in the url. I hope it will help some else in the future.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Start –301 redirect for "http://" to "http://www"
rewritecond %{http_host} ^testdomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.testsdomain.com/$1 [r=301,L]
# End - 301 redirect rule

# add trailing slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.testdomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check where is your form posting to. If form `action` is url without slash, then once you do `POST` request to it, htaccess will redirect you, and you will do a `GET` request to a page where you were supposed to post data. But since your request has been redirected and changed to `GET`, there will be no data submitted.

**Solution:** Either fix form action, or drop the code for adding trailing slash. And speaking of trailing slash, as far as I know, Joomla generates SEF links without it, so I wonder why you added it in the first place, you will do redirections each time you click on something